# Pigeon Hole problem on any set of distinct integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Show that given any set of seven distinct integers, there must exist two integers in this set whose sum or difference is a multiple of 10.

I'm having a hard time with this pigeon hole section. So I'm not sure how to go about this problem. I know that the first digit can be 1-9 and next 0-9 and so forth but the last must only be 0.

Answer (score 3):

The basic argument you want works something like this.  We can deal with all of the numbers modulo $10$, since divisibility by $10$ is all we care about.

Suppose the numbers somehow defied the condition.  Then all of the numbers would have to be different modulo $10$; otherwise, the difference between two numbers that are the same modulo $10$ would be divisible by $10$.

Now how about their sums?  There are six possible ways the sum of two numbers might be divisible by $10$:

- They are both equivalent to $0$ (modulo $10$).
- They are equivalent to $1$ and $9$.
- They are equivalent to $2$ and $8$.
- They are equivalent to $3$ and $7$.
- They are equivalent to $4$ and $6$.
- Or, they are both equivalent to $5$.

There are thus six different classes of numbers, and whenever two numbers are in the same class, either their sum or their difference (or both) must be divisible by $10$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: So the congruence classes mod 10 are pigeon holes?

Comment: @StillLearning: Not quite.  The equivalence classes are the bulleted items above.